# Merge sdb with sda in centos 7

Tags: centos

It is possible to merge sdb with sda to make it a longer partition instead of having two separate disks. All this without losing data

[image: My Disks informations]

Answer (score 0):

It appears your system is using LVM, you can add the second disk (sdb) to the volume group that currently consists of sda. Read up on LVM to learn how to extend you volume group and logical volume.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You already have everything set up that this is trivial!

Your / and your swap are on *volumes* in LVM, which means there's a nice abstraction layer between the actual storage devices storing the data and the device that you created the file system on.

When you run `sudo lvs` you should get a list of these *logical volumes* – at the very minimum there should be `swap` and `root`. Check out the "VG" column in the `lvs` output: that's the *volume group* they are all in. This group is who "owns" the physical disk partitions that the data is stored on. You can add more physical storage to that, easily!

Check `sudo pvs`: this list of the *physical volumes* and their owning volume group. I'd expect your `sudo pvs` to print a single entry:

```
  PV         VG                     Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda2  nameofyourvolumgroup   lvm2 a--  …     …
```

(where of course `nameofyourvolumegroup` is the name you also saw in `sudo lvs`)

So, let's add more physical volumes to the volume group. I'll assume you've got no data on /dev/sdb so far.

```bash
# Check the current state of all our 1 volume groups:
sudo vgs
# Note how much `VFree` there is within the `VSize`, and that there's only
# 1 PV (physical volume) in the volume group

# Create the data structures for a physical volume on /dev/sdb
sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb
# Add the physical volume to the volume group
sudo vgextend nameofyourvolumegroup /dev/sdb
# Done!

# Check the current state of all our 1 volume groups:
sudo vgs
# Note how much `VFree` there is within the `VSize`, and that there's now
# 2 PVs in the volume group
```

You can now easily add more space to your file systems. If they support live enlargement (all ext2,3,4 do, as well as XFS, so you're probably fine), you can simply say

```
sudo lvextend -r -L +1G nameofyourvolumegroup/root
```

to extend the size of the logical volume on which your root filesystem resides, and automatically also extend the filesystem size. Neat.